# How to find $\frac{\mathrm{d} r}{\mathrm{d}x}$?

Tags: derivatives

There are $2$ formulas, $x=r \cos \theta$ and $r=(x^2+y^2)^{1 \over 2}$ and I need to find $\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}x}$, the solution is $\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}x}=\cos \theta$.

This answer told me that it considers $y$ as a constant so that the answer is $\cos \theta$.

If I use $x=r \cos\theta$ to find $\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}x}$, the solution will be $\frac{1}{\cos \theta}$.

So why can't I consider $\theta$ as a constant?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take the opportunity to take the [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [how to ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), on [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and on writing down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: Why can't you consider $\theta$ as a constant? One reason that might be a bad idea is that it's _not_ a constant...

Answer (score 3):

$r$ is a function of independent variables $x$ and $y$; to find the partial derivative of $r$ w.r.t. $x$ you can treat $y$ as a constant: $\frac {\partial r} {\partial x}=(0.5)(x^{2}+y^{2})^{-0.5} (2x)$. Now you can use the fact that $x^{2}+y^{2}=r^{2}$ and $x =r\cos \theta$ to see that $\frac {\partial r} {\partial x} =\cos \theta$. There is no justification for treating $\theta $ as a constant. ($r$ and $\theta$ are independent variables. If you are differentiating a function of $r$ and $\theta$ w.r.t. $r$ you can treat $\theta$ as a constant).

Comment: If I use x=rcosθ to find dr/dx, 
dx=dr cosθ
dr/dx=1/cosθ
I don't get it.

Comment: When you partially differentiate w.r.t. $x$ you can only treat $y$ as a contant. You don't have the freedom to treat $\theta$ as a constant.

Comment: $\theta =\arctan (\frac y x)$ so $\theta $ depends on $x$.  @Student

Comment: r=(x^2+y^2)^0.5=(x^2+(rsinθ)^2)^0.5, I set y=rsinθ, the θ appears here. Can I say y depends on θ and θ depends on x so y depends on x?

Comment: ok, I get it. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

By the chain rule, $$dr=\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right)_ydx+\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}\right)_xdy=\frac{1}{2r}\left[\left(\frac{\partial r^2}{\partial x}\right)_ydx+\left(\frac{\partial r^2}{\partial y}\right)_xdy\right]=\frac{xdx+ydy}{r},$$where the subscripted variables on partial derivatives are held fixed. Hence $$\frac{dr}{dx}=\frac{x+y\frac{dy}{dx}}{r},$$where $\frac{dy}{dx}$ depends on the path along which we move in defining $\frac{dr}{dx}$. By contrast, the partial derivatives$$\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right)_y=\frac{1}{2r}\left(\frac{\partial r^2}{\partial x}\right)_y=\frac{x}{r}=\sec\theta,\,\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right)_\theta=\cos\theta$$have path-independent definitions.

Answer (score 1):

With $r= (x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$ the partial derivative $$\frac {\partial r}{\partial x} =(1/2)(x^2+y^2)^{-1/2}(2x)=\frac {x}{r}=\cos \theta$$

If you make the extra assumption that $\theta$ is constant then you get $\frac {dr}{dx}=\frac {1}{\cos \theta}$ but this is changing the question.

These are two different problems with two different results.

Answer (score 0):

First, a simple way to get the right answer: Take the partial derivative of both sides of $$r^2=x^2+y^2,$$and you get $$2r\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=2x.$$

Second, what's wrong with your argument "If I use $x=r \cosθ$ to find $\frac{\mathrm d r}{\mathrm dx}$, the solution will be $\frac{1}{\cos \theta}$": That would be right if $\theta$ were a constant. But of course $\theta$ depends on $x$; what you actually get is $$1=\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\cos(\theta)-r\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\sin(\theta).$$

$\newcommand\pd[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$
It turns out the OP is confused about why we can treat $y$ as a constant but not $\theta$. The answer to that has to do with what
$\pd rx$ means (and what's implicit in the notation):

### Partial Derivatives

If $f$ is a function of several variables an informal  definition of $\pd fx$ is "the derivative with respect to $x$, holding the other variables constant".

What that means depends on what the "other variables" *are*. In the informal sort of context we use in  calculus, maybe it would be better if the notation made explicit what variables  were the "other variables".

In any case, here we're given $r=r(x,y)$, so the "other variable" implicit in the notation $\pd rx$ is $y$; otoh $\theta$ simply is not one of the "other variables".

One could concoct a function $f$ so that $r=f(x,\theta)$. *If* $r$ had been defined that way then we *would* hold $\theta$ constant in calculating $\pd rx$. But that's different; here from the context it's clear we want $\pd rx$ *assuming* $r=r(x,y)$, not $r(x,\theta)$.

Comment: θ depends on x.
but y depends on r and θ, θ depends on x.
i am stupid i dont get it. sorry

Comment: I can't figure out what you don't get. $\theta=\arctan(y/x)$, so $\partial\theta/\partial x\ne0$.

Comment: because I don't get why you can treat y is a constant.

Comment: @Student The section I added at the bottom may help.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:
$$\begin{cases}x=r\cos t\\ y=r\sin t\end{cases} \iff r=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2} \quad (1)$$
If $x=r\cos t$ is the objective function, then $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac1{\cos t}$ (that is, $t$ is held constant).

If $x=r\cos t$ is associated with $y=r\sin t$ (apparently it is, because $r=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$ connects them), then the objective function is $(1)$. You can not ignore $y=r\sin t$, because as Kavi commented above:
$$\frac{y}{x}=\frac{\sin t}{\cos t} \Rightarrow \tan t=\frac yx \Rightarrow t=\arctan \left(\frac yx\right)$$
that is, $t$ is a function of $x$.

So, when you take partial derivative from $r=\frac{x}{\cos t}$, you must use the chain rule (or division rule):
$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\left(x\cdot \frac1{\cos t}\right)'_x=\frac{1}{\cos t}+x\cdot \frac{-1}{\cos^2t}\cdot (-\sin t)\cdot \frac{\partial t}{\partial x}=\\
\frac1{\cos t}+\frac{x\sin t}{\cos^2 t}\cdot \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac yx\right)^2}\cdot \left(-\frac{y}{x^2}\right)=\\
\frac1{\cos t}-\frac{x}{\cos t}\cdot \frac{y\sin t}{\underbrace{x^2+y^2}_{r^2}}\cdot \frac1{\cos t}=\\
\frac{1}{\cos t}-\frac{y\sin t}{r\cos t}=\frac1{\cos t}-\frac{\sin^2 t}{\cos t}=\cos t,$$ 
as expected.